# WPF Tabcontrol with timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I wm developing a WPF app which monitors some important data about a set of running processes and displays it. I have a few other tabs which has `UserControl`s that perform some other functions. The processes tabs uses a dispatcher timer to update the data every 1 second and the computation is relatively heavy. What I am trying to do here is to fire the timer only when the processes tabs is selected and stop it when some other tab is selected so that the data computation does not occur unnecessarily when the user is not viewing it. For my application the intermediate data values are irrelevant.

I was thinking of subscribing to the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events of the `UserControl` that is used as the tab content to start and stop the timer respectively. Are there any better alternatives?

What is the best method of achieving this functionality?

Comment: How about **Selected** and **Deselected** events? You can read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TabControl` has a [`SelectionChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.selectionchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Bind to that bad boy.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem selectedTab = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;  // Gets selected tab

        if (selectedTab.Name == "Tab1")
        {
            // Do work Tab1
        }
        else if (selectedTab.Name == "Tab2")
        {
            // Do work Tab2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the scenario clearly enough, but wouldn't it be easier to use the tabs `SelectionChanged` event and check whether the appropriate tab is selected or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectionChangedEventHandler to notify your application about the current view in tab control. 
You could use multithreading approach to do your job. Create multiple threads to compute the calculations resulting output required by different views added in different tabs of tab control. 
Keep on storing the data in collection and when ever user select the tab to open the view, pass computed data to UI thread and clear the collection in case of real time. 
Do the same for other views.